# How to combine rows in a table with some condition Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im having multiple tables and I combined them using 'join' (**code given below**), Now Im having a combined table which gives me correct number of answers for a particular user and for a particular quiz (given below):

[image]

I want to **add** or want to show **combined result** for same user and quiz like this (given below):

[image]

here is my blade code:

```
<thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Quiz Name</th>
                                <th>Quiz ID</th>
                                <th>UserName</th>
                                <th>User ID</th>
                                <th>Correct</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($data_correct as $row)
                                
                                <tr>
                                <td>{{$row->qname}}</td>
                                <td>{{$row->quiz_id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$row->user_id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$row->is_correct}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                
                            </tbody>
```

here is my controller function:

```
public function leaderboard(){

   
    $quizzes = (new Quiz)->allQuiz();

    $users = (new User)->allUsers();

    $data_correct = DB::table('results')
    ->join('answers', 'answers.id', 'results.answer_id')
    ->join('quizzes', 'quizzes.id', 'results.quiz_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'results.user_id')
    ->select('quizzes.qname', 'results.quiz_id','users.name' ,'results.user_id', 'answers.is_correct')->where('is_correct', 1)
    ->get();

    $data_wrong = DB::table('results')
    ->join('answers', 'answers.id', 'results.answer_id')
    ->select('results.quiz_id', 'results.user_id', 'answers.is_correct')->where('is_correct', 0)
    ->get();

    return view('leaderboard', compact('quizzes', 'data_correct', 'data_wrong'));

 }
```

**quizzes** table:
[image]

**answers** table:
[image]

**results** table:
[image]

Comment: can you show me few data from database

Comment: yeah sure, I added 3 more screenshots of tables, please see.

Comment: Please share your debugging attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql query to get the desired results would be

```sql
select
    results.quiz_id, results.user_id, users.name, quizes.qname as QuizName, quizes.id as QuizId, count(answers.is_correct) as Score
from results
join `users`
on results.user_id = users.id
join quizes
on results.quiz_id = quizes.id
join answers
on results.answer_id = answers.id
group by results.quiz_id,users.id
```

So I guess with Laravel query builder the query could be written as

```php
$summary = DB::table('results')
    ->join('users', 'results.user_id', 'users.id')
    ->join('quizes', 'results.quiz_id', 'quizes.id')
    ->join('answers', 'results.answer_id', 'answers.id')
    ->selectRaw("results.quiz_id as QuizId, results.user_id as UserId, users.name as UserName, quizes.qname as QuizName, quizes.id as QuizId, count(answers.is_correct) as Score")
    ->groupBy('results.quiz_id', 'results.user_id')
    ->get();
```

This should give you the desired data summary.

PS: Check and fix the Laravel query builder syntax for groupBy, am not sure about it.

Comment: @DaljitSingh Have updated the answer to provide raw sql and equivalent Laravel query builder statement. Pls check if this gives you the desired output

Comment: No sir its not working :-( ...here is the error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'quizmaster.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select results.quiz_id as QuizId, results.user_id as UserId, users.name as UserName, quizzes.qname as QuizName, quizzes.id as QuizId, count(answers.is_correct) as Score from `results` inner join `users` on `results`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `quizzes` on `results`.`quiz_id` = `quizzes`.`id` inner join `answers` on `results`.`answer_id` = `answers`.`id` group by `results`.`quiz_id`

Comment: please help me out..@Donkarnash

Comment: @DaljitSingh Pls look at the raw sql query and the Query Builder statement I have posted it includes `results.quiz_id` as well as `results.user_id` in the group by. The error shows that `results.user_id` is missing (not included) in the groupBy - which is why you are getting the error. Pls try the provided statement and let me know

Comment: @DaljitSingh For the output you desire, mysql needs to group the records from the results first by Quiz(results.quiz_id) further to calculate the Score of each user, mysql needs to club(aggregate) the values of `is_correct` for each user i.e. mysql needs to group the records first by `results.quiz_id` and then by `results.user_id`. So you need both in the groupBy clause. Hope it becomes clear now.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the above shouldn't work and give you the desired output. However if it still doesn't work for you pls post the schema (table structure) sql.

Comment: @DaljitSingh did it work for you? Since you have not responded with any errors, I assume that it worked

Comment: No sir, its not working. As I was out of town that's why was not able to respond. 

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? Can you please post the sql of the table schema?

Comment: Error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'quizmaster.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select results.quiz_id as QuizId, results.user_id as UserId, users.name as UserName, quizzes.qname as QuizName, quizzes.id as QuizId, count(answers.is_correct) as Score from results inner join users on results.user_id = users.id inner join quizzes on results.quiz_id = quizzes.id inner join answers on results.answer_id = answers.id group by results.quiz_id

Comment: From the error it seems you are still using only `results.quiz_id` in groupBy and not including `results.user_id`. Pls post the full query statement & schema sql for me to understand where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

try this bro

```
public function leaderboard(){
    $quizzes = (new Quiz)->allQuiz();
    $users = (new User)->allUsers();
    $data_correct = DB::table('users')
    ->join('answers', 'answers.id', 'results.answer_id')
    ->join('quizzes', 'quizzes.id', 'results.quiz_id')
    ->join('results', 'results.user_id', 'user.id')
    ->select(
       'quizzes.qname', 
       DB::raw('SUM(is_correct) as is_correct FROM answers where answers.id=results.answer_id'),
       'users.name' ,
       'results.user_id'
    )->
    where('answers.is_correct', 1)
    ->get();
    $data_wrong = DB::table('results')
    ->join('answers', 'answers.id', 'results.answer_id')
    ->select('results.quiz_id', 'results.user_id', 'answers.is_correct')->where('is_correct', 0)
    ->get();

    return view('leaderboard', compact('quizzes', 'data_correct', 'data_wrong'));

 }
```

Comment: Thanku sir for answering but there is error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: sorry bro you should remove answers in select i updated answer check it bro

Answer (score 0):

If I see that correctly, you use the variable "quizzes.qname" in the select query. But I only see name in the quizzes table. Try this:

```
public function leaderboard(){


$quizzes = (new Quiz)->allQuiz();

$users = (new User)->allUsers();

$data_correct = DB::table('results')
->join('answers', function ($join) {
    $join->on('answers.id', '=', 'results.answer_id')
        ->where('answers.is_correct', 1)
    })
->join('quizzes', 'quizzes.id', '=', 'results.quiz_id')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'results.user_id')
->select('quizzes.qname', 'results.quiz_id','users.name' ,'results.user_id', DB::raw('count(answers.is_correct) as score'))
->groupBy('results.quiz_id', 'results.user_id')
->get();

$data_wrong = DB::table('results')
->join('answers', function ($join) {
    $join->on('answers.id', '=', 'results.answer_id')
        ->where('answers.is_correct', 0)
    })
->select('results.quiz_id', 'results.user_id', DB::raw('count(answers.is_correct) as score'))
->groupBy('results.quiz_id', 'results.user_id')
->get();

return view('leaderboard', compact('quizzes', 'data_correct', 'data_wrong'));
```

}

I adjusted it again after your comment.

Comment: As there are multiple windows open I had taken screenshot from wrong database table, now I replaced quizzes table with correct one, please see. I'm using qname in program actually.

Comment: sir, same result as earlier, nothing happend. I replaced my function with yours.

Comment: Last attempt: I just noticed that I misunderstood your question. You may need to group all of the columns except the score. I have adjusted my code again and hope this works now: D

Comment: i think that groupby does not match for it

Comment: Why not?
I can't test it right now. That's why I thought that this was my last try.